# Using pscp.exe, how can I find files and then transfer from Unix to my windows system?

Tags: unix, vbscript, pscp

I can transfer files from Unix system to my windows system using pscp.exe as below:

(I am doing this in VBScript).

```
Function vbsMsgBox ()
    set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    sh.Run "C:\Users\msiddiq1\New\PSCP.EXE -pw password username@host:/b_st/batchrepo/BS31GZI C:\Users\msiddiq1\New"
End Function
```

But I want to transfer all the files returned from the below `find` command to my windows system:

```
find /b_st/batchrepo/BS31GZI -name "*900000007*" # It returns 6 filenames.
```

How can i merge this command to my above pscp command?.

I cannot create a new directory. Will i have to use a loop.
Please suggest.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out.

I tried this way:

```
Function vbsMsgBox ()
    set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    sh.Run "C:\Users\msiddiq1\New\PSCP.EXE -pw password username@host:/b_st/batchrepo/BS31GZI/*900000007* C:\Users\msiddiq1\New"
End Function
```

It worked just fine.

Source : http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter5.html

thanks.